# Form Closing dialog result appears in all forms

Tags: c#

I have this Code in the Form1 closing event:

```
private void MemberForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult del = MessageBox.Show("Save changes?", "Save",      MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (del == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // do something
    }
    if (del == DialogResult.No)
    {
        // do something
    }
    if (del == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

If I open **form2** from button in my **form1**, in **form2** closing event it will show me dialog result again. I want dialog result to be showed only in form1.
Why does this happen?

So my new question is: Can i do the same with save button? Preventing write the code second time?
Example

```
base.OnClosing(e);
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
        DialogResult del = MessageBox.Show("Save change?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (del == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
              ??????????????

            }
            if (del == DialogResult.No)
            {

                Form3 ss = new Form2();
                Hide();
                ss.ShowDialog();

            }
            if (del == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

    public bool saveToolStripMenuItemClicked { get; set; }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs  e)
    {
                Form3 ss = new Form3();
                Hide();
                ss.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Now i want when dialogresult (Yes) do the same with saveToolStripMenuItem_Click

Comment: Does form2 inherit from form1? How are you creating form2? Could you be adding this handler to form2 closing event anywhere?

Comment: Form2 ss = new Form2();
Hide();
ss.ShowDialog();

Comment: that is his code to show the form2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
         if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) 
         {
            //Some Code
         }
    }
```

Try this, this should only run when you close the whole application, make sure you put it on the main form.

The reason why yours is running on Form2 closing is because you have a memberclosing which from my understanding runs on all forms closing

**UPDATE**

I have edited the code above, if you put the code in that if statement then it will only run then the user clicks the close button

**UPDATE 2**

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);
    if(BackButtonClicked)
    {
      //code used for DialogResult.No answer
      BackButtonClicked = false;
    }
     if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) 
     {
        //Some Code
     }
}
    public bool BackButtonClicked { get; set; }

 private void backButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //Some code
          BackButtonClicked = true;
          //Some code, close form
        }
```

Comment: The only situation that it will work is when i open form 2 from dialog result.Example if (del == DialogResult.Yes){Form2 ss = new Form2();ss.showdialog();

Comment: Im not sure what you're trying to do then? From what the question is, it is saying that it shows the dialog for "Save Changes?" in form2 and you only want it to show in form1? is that right?

Comment: True. In my form 1 button code is Form2 ss = new Form2(); Hide(); ss.showdialog(); Maybe when i use hide, it doesnt understand that the form has closed.

Comment: So the issue is that when you close form2 it shows this dialog but you want it to show then you close form1? if so then this code will work, you can put the same code you have in your method in this method and e.Cancel = true; works in there too

Comment: because it is Protected that means it will only happen for form1

Comment: I want the dialog to be showed only if i will close Form1 from (x) in window title bar.  Not From my button Example: my button is "back button".

Comment: Ok, i understand what your are trying to do now. Hide(); classes as close. I have edited my answer, this should work

Comment: Thank you Sir.Where shoud i put this code? In Form1 Closing event? Is there any other way when i press "back" button to choose automatically dialogresul.No but without dialogresult to be showed?

Comment: Yeah put this code in the form1 closing event. You can create a bool property, when the back button is pressed, that property is true, then add an extra if statement to check if that property is true, if it is then (depending on the code you have for DialogResult.No) us the DialogResult.No code in that if statement, and if it is false then, do nothing and show the dialog. if the DialogResult.No is a big bit of code, put it into a method and call it in both locations. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you sir you helped, can you write an example?

Comment: Hope that answer helps you

Comment: forgot to add something at the bottom of the first if statement, i have added it now. Im just setting BackButtonClicked back to false, otherwise it will always run that code. Remember if you want that if statement to only run when they click the x button then put it into the second if statement

Comment: Thank you Brendon, you really helped me a lot. I have one more question making to you.See my First one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111551/discussion-between-brendon-and-dim).